# Cant connect to server when execute cordova emulate

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I use the example [LDAP Login with LDAP Server](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/authentication-security/using-ldap-login-module-to-authenticate-users-with-ldap-server-in-hybrid-applications/) to connect my app with LDAP.  I can connect the app example with the server. ALso I can modify the app and connect.

The problem is when I put the example in a Cordova Project for iOS when I put mfp as plugin.

I can see the app in _MobileBrowserSimulator and can connect to server but when I execute mfp cordoba emulate the app don't connect with server.

**--- UPDATE ---**

I use the same example that LDAP but this runs in mobile simulator but dont work in device. This is a simple example that run in simulator but not in device.

**main.js**

```
function getSecretData(){
var request = new WLResourceRequest("/Random/getInteger",
        WLResourceRequest.GET);


request.send().then(onSuccess, onFailure);
}


function onSuccess(r) {
   document.getElementById('guille').innerHTML = r;
}

function onFailure(r) {
     document.getElementById('guille').innerHTML = r;
}
```

**index.js**

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    WL.App.setServerUrl("http://127.0.0.1:10080/MyMFPProject",success, fail);
    WL.Client.connect();
}

function success(r){
    document.getElementById('guille').innerHTML = r;
}

function fail(r){
    document.getElementById('guille').innerHTML = "error: " +r;
}

function onSuccess(r) {
 document.getElementById('guille').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(r);
}

function onFailure(r) {
 document.getElementById('guille').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(r);
}
```

Comment: Provide your Cordova project then?

Comment: Its possible uses CORs with MF Server?

Comment: That will likely fail. Why are you answering my question with a question?! Do you want help or not? Explain your problem with any errors you get, provide your code and let us debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: based on the comment, it sounds like ATS is still enabled, in which requests will indeed fail. Disable ATS by adding the following to the application's *-info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

Read more here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/09/ats-and-bitcode-in-ios9/

---

The code looks fragile to me.
I would change it like below. If it will fail still then you need to create a test case demo of the failure. It sounds like it should fail also without anything related to LDAP...

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    WL.App.setServerUrl("http://127.0.0.1:10080/MyMFPProject",success, fail);

}

function success(r){
    document.getElementById('guille').innerHTML = r;
    WL.Client.connect({onSuccess: connectSuccess, onFailure: connectFailure);
}

function connectSuccess() {
    getSecretData();
    // ...
}

function connectFailure() {
    // handle connect failure
}

// the rest of the functions
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad code and discomfort. The problem is that the application fails in iOS9 but works well in IOS8. Thank you too!

Comment: Exists some way to modify the web.xml before MFP generates the WAR file? To add filter and filter mapping.